# Optimal css for a large HTML table

Tags: html, css, performance

Consider this simple table layout:

```html
<table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Cell1
          <td>Cell2
          ...
        <tr>
          ...
      <tbody>
    <table>
```

Consider also that this goes on for 100.000 of lines; a large table.

If I want to style the cells and I have a choice to add a class to each td, or to add a class to the table (or tbody).

### version 1

```css
    td.some-style {
      some definition
    }
```

and add a clase to each and every td

### or version 2

```css
table.some-style td {
   some definition
  }
```

and merely add a class to the table.

I've come to understand that browser read css right to left. And in version 1 would go an find all td dismissing quite fast the ones that don't have the class, Sounds fast to me. In the second version the browser would also first find all td for each go up a couple of levels and find, or not, the class. The first version however will explode the size of the html code as the class name needs to be copied in each td, in the second case it is only a view bytes. Remember the amount of td is quite larger

What would be best? Can I benchmark this in some way? Oh and rest assured the html is generated, not typed.

Comment: How much of a problem is the time taken? The second version looks easier for a human to understand and maintain - but perhaps if everything is generated automatically that isn't a consideration?

Comment: Indeed , maintenance is not a problem, bandwidth (response time) is. Also the trade off is needed on mobile devices. How well does a tablet responses to large data vs speedy css processing.